# Why does rvm expect version Ruby 2.6 when both Gemfile and path have 2.7.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, rvm, ruby-2.7

I’m using Mac OS Big Sur (11.6) with Rails 6.2, Ruby 2.7 and bash shell.  I’m noticing when I switch into my directory where my project is I get this message

```
$ cd ~/Documents/workspace//my-project/
Required ruby-2.6.7 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.6.7"'
```

This is odd because Ruby 2.7 is on my path and in my Gemfile

```
$ which ruby
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby
```

The Gemfile having this at the top

```
fail "run 'gem install bundler' to update your bundler version" unless Bundler::VERSION >= '2.0.0'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '~> 2.7.1'
```

I have this in my ~/.bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

But am unsure what else to check to remove this error message.  Why is it expecting Ruby 2.6 and how can I make it expect the proper version?

Comment: check if you have `.ruby-version` file in the root o the folder. If yes, check the contents of the file it should be `2.7.1` in order to select the desired version

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  This was indeed what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your ruby install has to be in the root directory.